# #AskFirebase FCM web push token invalidation time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Do FCM tokens generated using [Firebase JS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk) ever expire when user is offline too long?
For example, after calling the following code:

```
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
    updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
  } else {
    // Show permission request.
    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // Show permission UI.
    updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
  setTokenSentToServer(false);
});
```

The server has the client token. If the user clears the site data, the client no longer knows of this registration, and no one updates the server that the client is gone. So does it ever invalidates the token? If so, how long does it take to invalidate? I understand that FCM can save messages up to 28 days, so I'm assuming no less than that amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

Tokens might be invalidated for a number of reasons.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token):

> The registration token may change when:
>
> - The web app deletes the registration token.
> - The user clears browser data. In this case, call getToken to retrieve the new token.

The documentation doesn't say anything about expiration times, but your code should be prepared to handle these cases by detecting the change and sending the new token to your backend.

Comment: thx for the quick reply! I read the docs.. What I'd like to know is on the serverside, whether web tokens ever get invalidated if the client is offline after XXX amount of time, or are they up and alive until actively deleting the tokens?

Comment: The tokens don't have a declared expiration time.  You have to check error messages at the time of sending the message to find out if the token has become invalid. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

Comment: So for webpush, the only way for a token to get error is by actively deleting it.. This means I cannot rely on the error messages to detect how many messages are about to be delivered. So do you have any suggestion on how to let my customers know how many messages are likely to get delivered? I'm using cloud functions as server so I can't use XXMP to get delivery receipts. Maybe I can set a setBackgroundMessageHandler and call the server for every message delivery. Does that sound ok?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Please edit the question to more specifically explain the process you use to send messages, and the specific problem you're running into.  The documentation doesn't make any claims about token expiration, so I don't think you can count on that.